# Distribute people evenly among groups and tasks (Social Golfer Problem)

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, combinatorics

I need to write a program that sorts people into groups.

To give a little context:
The aim of the program is to create an equitable distribution of tasks and people for a school trip. Every day the groups are reshuffled and each group is assigned a task (cleaning, cooking, ...). So far, we have put the groups together randomly by drawing items from a bag. But every year the students complain if they are never in the same group as their friends or if they always have the task "cleaning". So I had the idea to develop a small program that solves this problem by dividing the students into groups where the people and tasks are evenly distributed.

The following specifications are requested:

1. We have a total of x people.
2. The people will be divided into y groups.
3. There are z days. On each day, the groups are mixed so that ideally, after all days, each person has been in a group with every other person at least once. The distribution should be even, i.e. everyone shares a group with every other person about the same number of times.
4. There are as many tasks as there are groups. For each day, each group is assigned one of these tasks. After all days, each person should have had each task about the same number of times.

Now about the algorithm. I think a solution to the Social golfer problem" ([www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/13/1/13](http://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/13/1/13)) might be a way to sort people into groups. But since there is the additional requirement of Tasks (people equally distributed among all groups), I really don't know how to approach this problem. After a bit of googling "Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem" and "The Running Dinner Problem" were some other keywords that popped up. Maybe that can be helpful?

Because I'm familiar with C#, I'll code the program in this language, but ultimately the underlying algorithm will be the same for all languages. So feel free to answer in any language you're familiar with.

If someone has a hint or even a full algorithm I would be very happy! Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure that can be solved. You create 2 conditions and that is something you will need brute force for. Try all combinations, get one that is best.

C#? Nice try, unless the group number is super small.. you may have more luck with some Tensor based approach running on the graphics card.

Comment: Look up a shuffle algorithm (it acts like shuffling a deck of cards). Then place the tasks around a virtual table and deal your shuffled virtual cards

Comment: Or, create a custom deck of physical cards, each card having the name of a participant on it. Set up a physical table, with places for each task. Each night, shuffle the cards, get one of the participants to cut the deck, then make a ceremonial deal. That way folks know it is random

Comment: This is awfully close to just being a plain maths problem right now, not a _programming_ problem. Even if the intent is to implement the solution using a programming language once you know which algorithm to implement, _right now_ this is a question for the [math.se] site.

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69325/social-golfer-problem-quintets for some links